# Why does my spinner not displaying selected item

Tags: kotlin, android-volley, spinner

I have a spinner in my activity that gets its data from a volley call. The data shows in the spinner. But when I click on a specific item in the spinner it does show.

Spinner Code

```
private fun spinner() {

    val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.report2Spinner)
    if (spinner != null) {
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, companyList)
        spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedItem = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                Toast.makeText(this@Report2Activity, selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                spinner.setSelection(position)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

declare of array that holds the volley data

var companyList: ArrayList = ArrayList()

Volley call

```
private fun jsonGetCompany() {
    //Declaring URL for JSON file
    val url = "https://mist.zp.co.za:6502/MIST.svc/CMP/M@H\$@203@R"

    val request = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            { response ->
                try {
                    val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Table")
                    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                        //Adding variables to JSONArray
                        val item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                        companyList.add(item.getString("Company"))
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }, { error -> error.printStackTrace() })
    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue?.add(request)
    //Setting timeout and retries
    request.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 3, 1f)
}
```

[image: Before choosing]
[image: While Choosing]
[image: After Choosing]

Here is the onCreate where I call spinner() and jsonGetCompany()

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report2)
    title = "Report 2"


    //Initialising Recyclerview
    recyclerViewReport2 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewReport2)
    val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
    recyclerViewReport2.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

    //Declaring Volley requestQueue for JSON calls
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    //Using JSON request function
    jsonGetCompany()
    spinner()

    val fromDatePicker: DatePicker = findViewById(R.id.report2FromDatePicker)
    val endDatePicker: DatePicker = findViewById(R.id.report2EndDatePicker)

    val buttonLoad: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonLoad)
    buttonLoad.setOnClickListener {
        fromDate = "${fromDatePicker.year}-${fromDatePicker.month + 1}-${fromDatePicker.dayOfMonth}"
        endDate = "${endDatePicker.year}-${endDatePicker.month + 1}-${endDatePicker.dayOfMonth}"
        Toast.makeText(this, "Company is: $selectedItem",       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        jsonRequestReport2Data()

        if (recyclerViewReport2.isNotEmpty()) {
            company.clear()
            report2Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I dont understand your problem but your code looks fine. What's happening exactly when your spinner initialize and you select the item? Can you clarify please.

Comment: The item in the spinner I select does not show that it is the selected Item. Even the toast shows that nothing is selected it gives me an empty toast

Comment: @Berkay Kireçci I've uploaded screen shots that shows what I mean

Comment: I just added answer but if toast shows that nothing is selected, there should be another problem.

Comment: Maybe my volley request is calling the data everytime I use the spinner so it doesn't save the selected Item? But how do I save my volley request in an array, and use that array for my spinner?

Comment: Can you post activity class where you call spinner() and  jsonGetCompany() .

Comment: I've added for you

Comment: Can you try to call spinner() in volley function after this line : companyList.add(item.getString("Company")) .

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. Thanks alot been on that since Friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :** Its because `jsonGetCompany()` and  `spinner()` is called same time but volley works asynchronously. You should set adapter after volley gets data from server. Calling this server call from activity is not proper way but it's completely different subject. You can simply edit your code like :

```
 try {
      val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Table")
      for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
      //Adding variables to JSONArray
           val item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
           companyList.add(item.getString("Company"))
      }
      setSpinner()
 } catch (e: JSONException) {
     e.printStackTrace()
 }
```

Glad i could help.

Comment: This did not work gives me the same display